# Using importValue inside If Condition in aws cloudformation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to find a way to use ImportValue inside If function but can't find a proper syntax. Any help is appreciated.

Below the code I'm trying:

```
SomeTaskdefinition:
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    Family: 'FamilyName'
    ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: ContainerName
      Image: 'imagename:net/v2/'
      Environment:
      - Name: ENV_VARIABLE_1
        Value:
          Fn::If:
            Fn::Equals:
              Fn::ImportValue:
                !Sub "${ImportStackname}-ECSCluster"
              ''
            'notpresent'
            'present'
```

Answer (score 6):

I come across here with similar problem.. my idea was to either be able specify `DatabaseHost` as parameter, if left empty - value should be taken from `DatabaseStack` export. Here is my sample code - it uses `!ImportValue` inside `!If` function. You will get the idea (instead of constructing only Value - construct whole Name Value list object)

```
Conditions:
  DatabaseHostPresent: !Not [ !Equals [ !Ref DatabaseHost, ""]]

Resources:
 ...
       ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Sub ${ApplicationName}-web-${EnvironmentName}
          Environment:
            - !If
              - DatabaseHostPresent
              - Name: DB_HOST
                Value: !Ref DatabaseHost
              - Name: DB_HOST
                Value: !ImportValue
                  Fn::Sub: ${DatabaseStack}-EndpointAddress
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible. You cannot use `ImportValue` inside an `Equals` function.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Equals function, but I definitely can't use it inside 'Condition' part. The only work around is lambda for now.

Comment: Still the case 4 years later. Thanks AWS!

Comment: My solution is working and looking nice imho

Answer (score 2):

Another way to work around this is to use a nested template:

- Add a Parameter to the Child template
- In the Parent template, use the Import to populate the Parameter
- In the Child template, you can do everything you'd want including using it in the `Conditions` section

Untested example:

```
# in Parent
Resources:
  ChildStack:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        Stackname: {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub "${ImportStackname}-ECSCluster"}
      TemplateURL: './child.yaml'

# in Child
Parameters:
  Stackname:
    Type: String
    Default: ''
Conditions:
  HasStack: !Not [!Equals [!Ref Stackname, '']]
Resources:
  SomeTaskdefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: 'FamilyName'
      ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: ContainerName
        Image: 'imagename:net/v2/
        Environment:
        - Name: ENV_VARIABLE_1
          Value: !If [HasStack, 'present', 'notpresent']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of intrinsic function I've obtained the result:

```yaml
parameter1: !If
    - condition1
    - !ImportValue 
      Fn::Sub: "${name}-dev-parameter"
    - AWS::NoValue
```

Make sure to use the sequence of intrinsic function as I've listed. It seems to be the only way.

Comment: This did work for me. Only that I landed on this solution after figuring it out after many attempts.